# Get number of page frames in use

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I want to know **the number of page frames that this process is using**.

I am not sure if **this** is the same as **the number of page table entries**.

Anyway I want to know both, if possible. Which system call can be helpful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783981/is-number-of-frame-number-of-pageslinux

Comment: You need to be more specific. The number of page frames in use can change constantly. The number of page table entries is NOT the same. There can be (and usually are) page table entries without associated page frames.